# Get the url parameter in the iframe at the target page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have created a website called `https:www.somePage.com` and I'm rendering this page inside another website using `iframe`. Since I'm using the same `iframe` in different websites, **to track the website that using my `https:www.somePage.com` I'm adding a parameter called `page` in the iframe src**. So the iframe will be like

```
<iframe src="https:www.somePage.com?page=company_name" width="100" height="250">
```

How can I access the parameter **`page`** in my website `https:www.somePage.com`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I get query string values in JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/901115/how-can-i-get-query-string-values-in-javascript)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**In javascript using `location.search` you can get the parameters. But you've to split it and get the desired value.**

Comment: Correct, but i think in this case it would be window.top.location.search as he's accessing the containing page of that specific iframe.

Comment: @RuslanAbuzant it'll work fine, he is appending parameters in the iframe src and trying to access it in the iframe window.

Comment: Let me try somehting with location.search and will get back to you. Thanks

Comment: I'm not getting the url when the page is in `iframe`, but getting correctly when it's directly opening in the browser

Comment: @SyamPillai working fine for me. Can you share the parent and child iframe codes. So that I can check.

Comment: Yeah dude. Did some stupid mistakes. Now working fine. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

The webpage containing the iframe is considered the HTTP_REFERER in server terms, and the window.top.locarion.href in client terms. So based on your development environment, you can fetch that. In PHP that would be `$ref = $_SERVER["HTTP_REFERRER"]` and in JS that would be `window.top.location.href`, good luck.

Comment: Actually I'm not accessing the containing page's url. I want to get the **exact iframe src**